# PHP Array and unset function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => abc@gmail.com
                [timestamp] => 2013-05-03 09:20:01
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => def@gmail.com
                [timestamp] => 2013-05-03 09:20:23
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [email] => ghi@gmail.com
                [timestamp] => 2013-05-03 09:20:43
            )

    )
```

I want this to be as simple as like this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => abc@gmai1.com
        [1] => def@gmail.com
        [2] => ghi@gmail.com
    )
```

I have tried unset function but it still doesn't work as i expected.

I am not big into array concept and hence my stupid questions !!! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($foo as $key=>$value)
{
  $foo[$key] = $value['email'];
}
```

Comment: @hjaffer2001: you should consider to accept [walkhand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1441894/walkhard) answer. Filter is better and more elegant respect this "flat-foreach" :)

Answer (score 6):

I think that it'd be better to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead of `unset`:

```
function filter($x)
{
    return $x['email'];
}

$emails = array_map('filter', $your_array);
```

This basically will map your input array into output array using `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pick from your old array what you want and put it in a new one.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $containedArray)
{
  $newArray[] = $containedArray['email'];
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $array = Array
    (
        Array
            (
                email => 'abc@gmail.com',
                timestamp => '2013-05-03 09:20:01'
            ),

        Array
            (
                email => 'def@yahoo.co.in',
                timestamp => '2013-05-03 09:20:23'
            ),

        Array
            (
                email => 'ghi@gmail.com',
                timestamp => '2013-05-03 09:20:43'
            ),

);


foreach ($array as $array){
   $newArray[] = $array['email'];
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to unset anything. Just assign the appropriate value:

```
<?php
$array = array(
      array(
            "email" => 'aaa@aaa.com',
            "timestamp" => 2,
            ),
      array(
            "email" => 'bbb@aaa.com',
            "timestamp" => 3,
            ),
);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
      $array[$key] = $value["email"];
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <?php
  $array= array(
    0 => array
        (
           'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'timestamp' =>' 2013-05-03 09:20:01'
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'email'=> 'def@gmail.com',
            'timestamp' => '2013-05-03 09:20:23'
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'email'=> 'ghi@gmail.com',
            'timestamp' => '2013-05-03 09:20:43'
        )

 );

foreach($array as $key => $data)
{
$array[$key]=$data['email'];
}
  print_r($array);
```

?>

You will get

```
   Array
    (
     [0] => abc@gmai1.com
     [1] => def@gmail.com
     [2] => ghi@gmail.com
    )
```